# Obtaining the nth iteration of a nested loop?

Tags: python-3.x, generator

I have this snippet that 'generates' the centers of figures in my GUI... The probem is that is too slow because the solution iterates too much. So I'm wondering how to implement a generator to take exacle value I need.

```
from pprint import pprint


def center(i, j):
    s = 50
    for k, v1 in enumerate(range(int(s / 2), s * 8, s)):
        for n, v2 in enumerate(range(int(s / 2), s * 8, s)):
            if (i, j) == (k, n):
                return (v1, v2)

pprint(center(0,0))  # -> (25, 25)
pprint(center(6,3))  # -> (325, 175)
```

So I made this generator:

```
def centerGenerator():
    s = 50
    for k in range(int(s / 2), s * 8, s):
        for n in range(int(s / 2), s * 8, s):
            yield k, n

def center(i, j):
    for c in centerGenerator():
        pass # how to take only c(i,j) from the Generator?

pprint(center(0,0))  # -> (25, 25)
pprint(center(6,3))  # -> (325, 175)
```

But idk how to implements it. Any thoughts?

Comment: What about using def center(i, j): return((25+50*i, 25+50*j)) ?

Comment: Yeah sure. I know it's a trivial math problem. We can solve with equations, arithmetic progressions... etc. But my interest is: its possible to obtain only the nth iteration of a loop (nested loop) without go through the entire path of iterations?

Comment: You ask: "Is it possible to obtain only the n-th iteration of a loop (nested loop) without going through the entire path of iterations?" Let's skip considering if it does make sense to have a loop without wanting the loop to run and give an answer. The answer is: "It depends". In case of your script it is possible. Just replace  "if (i, j) == (k, n): return (v1, v2)" with "return((25+50*i, 25+50*j))".